# Can we add wifi signal to turtlebot_dashboard

Tags: ros, wifi, turtlebot, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to monitor the wifi signal from the asus 1215n laptop on my turtlebot from the dashboard node. Is anyone else interested in this option. If no one is willing to work on it, where should I start? Maybe  there is some code for the Pr2 I could look at to get me started in the right direction. Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12714/can-we-add-wifi-signal-to-turtlebot_dashboard.../) by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 458 on 2012-01-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-02-01**:
https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/123

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2012-01-23**:
Thanks for the replys. I added a ticket. I hope someone more capable than I picks up on it...

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-01-23**:
please file a ticket :)

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2012-02-18**:
Thanks I Heart Robotics/WilliamMorris for working on this ... You guys just define Turtlebot Awesomeness ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 is a fairly unique case because it uses a Linksys WRT610Nv2 access point as its wireless client, and signal information isn't reported to the dashboard.

You may be able to find useful code, frameworks or ideas in the [linux networking](http://ros.org/wiki/linux_networking) stack, but the documentation there is pretty sparse. I would start by digging through the wpa_supplicant_node to see if it's useful or not.

I don't know of anyone else that is working on this at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2